# How to set default index when using viewpager2, using setCurrentItem initialises the viewpager with 0 index as default and then navigates to the index

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am using setCurrentItem , what it does is set's up my viewpager2 with the default 0 index and then it slides and opens the index which i pass in setCurrent Item . I want is to initialise and remain on the same index which i am passing.

currently i am using
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index,false)

what it does is sets up view pager and then navigates to the specified index.

i am looking for something which sets up viewpager to the specified index and not navigate after setting up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly it doesn't seems to exist yet

The api design forces us to face this behavior as currently you can't use setCurrentItem before adding an adapter on the viewPager2.
But at the same time adding an adapter directly load the content at index 0.